# Problem with passing viemodel from view, into controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have problem with passing viewmodel from view into controller. I dont know why, but model in my controller is empty. Here is my code.

My viewmodel includes two data models.

Sory for this two lines, but I have to write something stupid here, only because editor blocks my example because is looks like that my post is mostly code and pushes me to add more details :-)

viewmodel

```
    public class ModShopView
{
    public IEnumerable<ModShopText> Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ModShop> EshopItems { get; set; }

}
```

model eshopitems

```
    public class ModShop
{
    [Required]
    public int IdZbozi { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NazevZbozi { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Cena { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Vat { get; set; }

    public int Mnozstvi { get; set; }

}
```

controller

```
        [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Shop(ModShopView mymodel, IFormCollection collection)
    {
        //return View("objednavka");
        string result = string.Empty;
        string nazev = string.Empty;
        int pocet = 0;



        foreach (var items in collection)
        {

            if ((pocet = int.TryParse(items.Value, out pocet) ? pocet : 0) > 0)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    nazev = mymodel.EshopItems.Where(x => x.IdZbozi == Convert.ToInt32(items.Key)).Select(x => x.NazevZbozi).ToString();
                }

                result = "Key=" + items.Key + " value=" + items.Value + " název:" + nazev.ToString() + "<br/>" + result;

            }
        }

        return Content($"result: {result}");
    }
```

view

```
@model MojeIdentita.Models.ModShopView
@using MojeIdentita.Helpers
@{
    string lang = (string)ViewContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] ?? "cz";
    ViewData["Title"] = Html.GetLangResourceHtml(lang, "menuShop", true);

}

<h1 class="text-left" role="heading" aria-level="1">@Html.GetLangResourceHtml(lang, "menuShop", true)</h1>
<div class="">
    <div>
        @Html.Raw(Model.Description.FirstOrDefault().Part1)
    </div>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @foreach (var Polozky in Model.EshopItems)
        {

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 city"><p>@Polozky.NazevZbozi</p></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p>@Polozky.Vat</p></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p>@Polozky.Cena</p></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><p><input type="text" id="inputpocet" name="@Polozky.IdZbozi" /></p></div>
            </div>

        }
        <input type="submit" value="@Html.GetLangResourceHtml(lang, "txtObjednat", true)" class="order" />
    }

    </div>
```

Please, could you help me to find, where I make mistake?
Thanx

Comment: What are you expecting the model passed to your controller to contain?

Comment: @Jan Šalomoun - Are you using ASP.NET Framework or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @Jackdaw - NET.Core

Comment: @DaveBarnett - I would like to get data from my order form. There is simple list with product items and I need to check, product with filled number of ordered items.